# Reverse proxy for backend apps with IIS 8, ARR and URL rewrite on 1 server

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, arr

Situation is that I have 2 backend apps and I need to set up HTTPS access for them. I install IIS 8 with ARR and URL rewrite module on the server. Than I install 2 https certificates and create an empty website with binding on 443 port 
 with second app https certificate. First app is set upped on 8081 ports and second app on port 80. The problem is that I can access via https only to first app and second app could be accessed via http only. So I am trying to set up reverse proxy, so I could access to the second app via https. I wrote 2 inbound rules in URL rewrite, but I got issue when I try to access to second app it is pointing not to localhost:80 but it pointing to localhost:8081. any suggestions why it happen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="App2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^app2/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:80/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirection" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^app2/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="443" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://app2/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is rather difficult to understand what you really set up on the machine. The simplest should be creating a single site with two SNI bindings, who takes care of all incoming HTTPS requests, then forward them based on host header to the backend HTTP applications via ARR. Your second rule seems to be broken (`https://apps2/{R:0}` makes no sense), so please go back to a white board and redo the work.

Comment: @LexLi I did what you advice to me but got same result. Now I have 1 simple site with 2 SNI binding https.app1.com and https.app2.com. tan I set up simple rewrite based on http_host, but the result sam when I try to access https:app2.com I open app1 homepage with app2 domain name.

Comment: I think the problem is that my second app is on port 80 and due that I ave such issues